# Bind sub-model to view in backbone / marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, marionette, backbone-relational

I have a User model that has a BankAccount model and I have view who's model attribute is set to the User model and in that view's template I reference an attribute of the bank account:

```
<%= bankAccount.get('description') || 'No linked account' %>
```

If I updated the bankAccount the view doesn't pick up on the change:

```
user.get('bankAccount').set('description', 'foobar')
```

I tried adding the following in the initialize on the User model but it didn't work either.

```
initialize: function() {
  var self = this;

  this.on('change:bankAccount', function() {
    self.get('bankAccount').bind('change', function() {
      self.trigger('change');
    });
  });
}
```

Any suggestions? Also, both these models use backbone relational, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your view subscribe to the `description` change event on the BankAccount model and re-render itself

```
UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.get('bankAccount').on('change:description', this.render, this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Backbone-relational Events](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#events) you will see that you can bind to `update:<key>` and further below there is an example (which I copy/pasted below) on how to listen to changes/updates on `HasMany` and `HasOne` relations

```
// Use the 'update' event to listen for changes on a HasOne relation 
// (like 'Person.livesIn').
paul.bind( 'update:livesIn', function( model, attr ) {
    console.debug( 'update to %o', attr );
});
```